# Is there a way to search files with netrw similar to find command in linux?

Tags: netrw

Is there a way to search files with netrw similar to find command in linux?

So in command line I can do

```
find . -name "pattern"
```

Is there something similar in netrw?

Comment: In netrw? Not to my knowledge. In Vim? Yes of course, there are many ways to find files, including that very same command. But `find . -name "pattern"` on its own would be just as pointless in Vim as in your shell. You want to find files, OK, but what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: One nice way would be to `:.!find . -type f -name "patern"` in an empty buffer and then use `gf` on each entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have plugins to do so :

- [Ctrl-P](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/)
- [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025)

Or you can do by hand :

With a unix command from vim :

```
:!find . -name "pattern"
```

With the `Explore` command :

```
:Explore pattern
```

Based on [this post](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_files_in_subdirectories) this function is available through the `netrw.vim` file.

Comment: +1 for Ctrl-P, such a great plugin.

Comment: Yes, I recommend using `ag` with it : https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- seems you have a number of people answering who don't use gvim because such search support is easily seen under the netrw menu.  So, look at :help netrw-star . In particular,  :Explore */pattern .